# Add Google APIs Client Library in symfony 3

Tags: symfony, google-oauth, bundle, google-api-php-client

I want to install the "Google APIs Client Library" in my symfony 3 project, but I don't know how to use it.

I install the library from "https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#download-the-release" with this command:

composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"

Next, I try adding namespace in AppKernel.php file, "bundles" array, but I dont know what namespace is or where can I find the namespace. Then I receive this error every time:

```
Attempted to load class "Google_Client" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller".
```

This is my small function:

```
    /**
    * @Route("/api/oAuth/login", name="api_oauth_login")
    */
    public function oAuthLoginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("My Application");
        $client->setDeveloperKey("MY_SIMPLE_API_KEY");
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this library integration?

Comment: try with `new \Google_Client();`

Comment: Than you, this fix my problem, now works fine!!

Comment: Please dont edit answers into your question. That is what answers are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library don't use a namespace so you should refer to the class with a trailing slash before the classname as example:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
```